# Multiple instances of winword.exe in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I have a vb.net application which open word 2016 document one by one and uses the below code for it

```
   Public oWA As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
   Public oDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
   oWA = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
   --below code line opens multiple word document one by one
  oDoc = oWA.Documents.Open(fileName, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, 
   objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, 
    objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing)
```

The issue is sometimes application is hanged and stop processing word files. Then I saw two instances of Winword.exe in task manager -> Process. When I kill the one with lower memory then application starts automatically. How these two instances are generated. Can I prevent it? For resolving this I created a function to kill the winword.exe instance but it is not working.

```
Private Function KillMultipleWord()

    Dim currentProcess As Process()
    currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("winword")
    If currentProcess.Length > 1 Then
        Dim totalBytesOfMemoryUsed As Long = 0
        Dim cmptotalBytesOfMemoryUsed As Long = 0
        Dim cmpProc As System.Diagnostics.Process = Nothing
        For Each proc As System.Diagnostics.Process In currentProcess
            totalBytesOfMemoryUsed = proc.WorkingSet64
            If cmptotalBytesOfMemoryUsed < totalBytesOfMemoryUsed Then
                If cmpProc IsNot Nothing Then
                    cmpProc.Kill()
                End If
                cmpProc = proc
                cmptotalBytesOfMemoryUsed = totalBytesOfMemoryUsed
            Else
                proc.Kill()
            End If
        Next
        cmpProc = Nothing
    End If
    KillMultipleWord = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. The code snippet you posted does not contain the "looping" functionality so we can't see exactly where the problem is. Most likely, however, you're calling `New Word.Application` in each iteration of the loop. You should call it only once, before the loop, and loop opening the documents - all in the same instance of the Word.Application. When you're done with a document be sure to close it *and release it*. When you're done with the Word.Application, be sure to release it correctly, as well. Otherwise your code will never run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
oDoc.Close()
```

after every document, and

```
oWA.Quit()
```

when you're finished.